# Semi-direct products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need some help to show that $\text{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$ is a semi-direct product of the quaternion group and the cyclic group $C_{3}$. Any ideas? I don't want to write the elements of $\text{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$, it seems like a very ugly method.

thanks

Comment: Look at $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$. Find a copy of $Q_8$, $H$ say, and a copy of $C_3$, $K$ say. Do they intersect trivially? Is one normal? Does $G=KH$?

Answer (score 5):

An upper triangular matrix with all non-zero entries equal to $1$ and a lower triangular matrix of same type generate two cyclic subgroups of order $3$ - which are Sylow-3 subgroups. The number of Sylow-3 subgroups in $G=SL(2,3)$ is either $1$ or $4$; but by the remark, it should be $4$; say $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4$. Hence index of normalizer of a Sylow-3 subgroup is $4$ : $[G:N(P_1)]=4$ i.e. $G$ has a subgroup of index $4$. (note that then $|N(P_1)|=6$)

Then there will be a homomorphism $\phi\colon G\rightarrow S_4$, with $ker(\phi)\subseteq N(P_1)$ (*Generalised Cayley's Theorem*).

- If $ker(\phi)=N(P_1)$, then it will be a normal subgroup of $G$, and $P_1$ is a characteristic subgroup of $N(P_1)$ (*since it is unique subgroup of order 3*); hence $P_1\triangleleft G$, contradiction.
- If $ker(\phi)=P_1$, then $P_1\triangleleft G$, contradiction
- If $ker(\phi)=\{1\}$, then $G\cong S_4$ contradiction (*why?*)
- Therefore, $|\ker(\phi)|=2$, and so $ker(\phi) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.
  Then $G/ker(\phi)$ will be isomorphic to a subgroup of order 12 in $S_4$; we must have $G/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong A_4$.

Since $A_4$ has a normal subgroup of index 3, by correspondence theorem, $G$ has a normal subgroup of index $3$, containing $ker(\phi)=\mathbb{Z}_2$. This normal subgroup of index $3$ (hence order 8) will be Sylow-2 subgroup of $G$.

Since $G$ has unique element of order $2$; the normal Sylow-2 subgroup will also have unique element of order 2, it is either $\mathbb{Z}_8$ or $\mathbb{Q}_8$. It can not be $\mathbb{Z}_8$ because the normal subgroup of index $3$ in $A_4$ contains 3 subgroups of index $2$; the corresponding subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_8$ should also contain three subgroups of index $2$, contradiction.

We have shown

> $G$ has normal Sylow-2 subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}_8$

The rest part is then easy to answer the question:

Since $Q_8 \triangleleft G$, $\mathbb{Z}_3\leq G$, so $Q_8\mathbb{Z}_3\leq G$, and computing order we see $Q_8\mathbb{Z}_3=G$.

Therefore $Q_8\triangleleft G$, $\mathbb{Z}_3\leq G$, $G=Q_8\mathbb{Z}_3$, and $\mathbb{Z}_3 \cap Q_8=\{1\} \Rightarrow G=Q_8\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way is just to check the elements.  Here are two ways to prove it, but they use more group theory.

**2-local**: If *q* is (a field whose order is) an odd prime power, then SL<sub>2</sub>(*q*) has quaternion Sylow 2-subgroups *H* generated in one of two ways depending on *q* mod 4.  Check that in fact the standard Sylow *q*-subgroup *K* (consisting of upper-triangular matrices with 1s on the diagonal) normalizes *H* when *q* = 3, and that by order considerations the resulting semi-direct product is the entire group.

**3-local:** If *q* is (a field whose order is) a prime power, then SL<sub>*n*</sub>(*q*) has Sylow *q*-subgroups consisting of upper-triangular matrices with 1s on the diagonal, and its normalizer is all upper-triangular matrices (with determinant 1).  However, when *n* = 2 and *q* = 3, the only possible diagonals are [1,1] and [−1,−1], both of which centralize the Sylow *q*-subgroup.  Hence the Sylow *q*-subgroup has a normal complement, by Burnside, and in this case that complement is the entire Sylow 2-subgroup, which is quaternion as usual since *n* = 2 and *q* is odd.

Maybe though you are just asking how to remember which direction the semi-direct product goes.  I always forget, even though it should be important enough for me to remember.  I developed these two ways to remember:

**Normalizer mnemonic:**  SL<sub>2</sub>(odd) generally has quaternion Sylow 2-subgroups; call one *H*.  In this group of order 24, the normalizer is either all of SL<sub>2</sub>(q) and we are done, or the normalizer is just *H* itself.  In the latter case, we'd have that *K* was normal by Burnside and the fact that proper subgroups of Q<sub>8</sub> have 2-groups as automorphism groups.  So either you have C<sub>3</sub> acting on Q<sub>8</sub> or Q<sub>8</sub> acting on C<sub>3</sub>.  Both semi-direct products occur, but only one of them is SL<sub>2</sub>(3); how do you remember which one?

Well, SL<sub>2</sub>(K) is usually a perfect group; it usually has no abelian quotients.  The only exceptions to these matrix group identities for finite fields are always in the defining characteristic.  SL<sub>2</sub>(2) has an abelian quotient of order 2, and SL<sub>2</sub>(3) has an abelian quotient of order 3.  Hence it is the C<sub>3</sub> acting on Q<sub>8</sub>.

**Quotient mnemonic** The other mnemonic is that PSL(2,3) = Alt(4) has a normal Sylow 2-subgroup, and Z(SL(2,3)) has order 2, so SL(2,3) has a normal Sylow 2-subgroup (which is quaternion as usual).  This fits in with the other exceptions PSL(2,4) = PSL(2,5) = Alt(5) and PSL(2,9) = Alt(6).

I'd be interested in a better mnemonic:

> **Is there some natural matrixy thing that SL<sub>2</sub>(3) acts on as a 3-cycle?**

Is there some general reason SL<sub>2</sub>(*q*) would be acting on a vector space over the field with 2-elements?

Comment: Jack, since $q=p^n$, when you say Sylow $q$-subgroup, it should be $p$-subgroup, right?

Comment: @Nathan: yup, though I like thinking of them as Sylow q-subgroups since they still have order a power of q, and the same as structure as their p^1-friends if one allows more general exponents.