# Semi direct product of Quaternion group with cyclic group of order p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, semidirect-product

I am interested in knowing the **semi-direct product** of Quaternion group $Q_8$ with $c_p$, i.e. cyclic group of order $p$ where $p$ is a odd prime.

We know that $\text{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{3})$ is a semi-direct product of $Q_8$ and $C_3$ from here. [Semi-direct products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71378/semi-direct-products).

Can we generalize above result to $c_p$ for odd prime $p$. Please help.